# Apeex 5.0 "static file support"

Tags: oracle-apex

APEX 5.0: There are issues with the configuration of the Static Files in your environment

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are receiving that message when you try to login into the APEX Development Environment. Searching for that message on Google retrieves a number of hits, one of them is for example my blog posting

[APEX 5.0: There are issues with the configuration of the Static Files in your environment](http://www.inside-oracle-apex.com/apex-5-0-there-are-issues-with-the-configuration-of-the-static-files-in-your-environment/)